# Unit test - "NameError: global name is not defined"

Tags: python, math, import, doctest

I am trying to figure out how to write unit tests for my functions in Python - here's the code written below:

```
def num_buses(n):
    import math
    """ (int) -> int

    Precondition: n >= 0

    Return the minimum number of buses required to transport n people.
    Each bus can hold 50 people.

    >>> num_buses(75)
    2
    """
    bus = int()
    if(n>=0):
        bus = int(math.ceil(n/50.0))
    return bus
```

I am attempting to write test code but my results fail - here's the code I have started with:

```
import a1
import unittest


class TestNumBuses(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Test class for function a1.num_buses. """
    def test_numbuses_1(self):
        actual = num_buses(75)
        expected = 2
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    # Add your test methods for a1.num_buses here.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

When I run the module by pressing F5 - this is what I get -

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_numbuses_1 (__main__.TestNumBuses)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\1-blog-cacher\TestNumBuses.py", line 8, in test_numbuses_1
    actual = num_buses(75)
NameError: global name 'num_buses' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.050s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

It should pass since the number of passengers are 75 and each bus can hold a maximum of 50 people - anything more than that will result in a rounding up of the figures.

Comment: You asked this twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848275/unit-test-nameerror-global-name-is-not-defined

Comment: This is the second question I have found that the OP has duplicated to garner more answers. Voting to close.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your code is in module `a1`, try prefacing `num_buses` with `a1`, so `a1.num_buses`. The problem is that your unittests are in a different module, and the `num_buses` function from that module is referenced as `a1.num_buses` in the test's namespace, hence the `global` error. Therefore change your test to:

```
class TestNumBuses(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Test class for function a1.num_buses. """
    def test_numbuses_1(self):
        actual = a1.num_buses(75)
        expected = 2
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error states a problem with num_buses. Try

```
actual = a1.num_buses(75)
```